# Where are errors stored?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I was wondering where errors are stored in Javascript. An error is thrown and passed to `catch()` in the MDN example below. My question is how does `catch()` get the error object? Where is the thrown error stored to be a parameter for `catch()` later?

```js
try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  // expected output: ReferenceError: nonExistentFunction is not defined
  // Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}
```

Comment: "*My question is how does catch() get the error object?*" the entire purpose of the `catch()` receive a thrown value. The language + environment ensures that's what it does. The same way `2 + 2` is ensured to be `4`.

Comment: Primitives are always stored on stack though. I was asking how JS stores an error and makes it accessible.

Comment: *Primitives are always stored on stack* — no

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown by the javascript runtime because you are calling an undefined function. Something like this happens under the hood

```
const func = () => {
  try {
    throw new ReferenceError(
      "nonExistentFunction is not defined"
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

func();
```

`catch` just capture this error from `try` scope